# How to get test case name in WebdriverIO in time of execution

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver-io

Was looking over WebdriverIO API and google's search as well but could  not find how to get name of test case in the time of execution. Anyone has experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution... Using beforeSuite and beforeTest hooks can do a job